# Proper Ruby Convention for Calling Self Methods

Tags: ruby, module, naming-conventions, self

I have quick question about naming convention. In the example below I have a module that I want to include, but only want the top function accessible. I use `self` to achieve this, but I was wondering if it's proper to call self before every self function or if I'm good excluding that?

```
module MyMod
  def call_all_functions
    first_function # should this be self.first_function?
    second_function # should this be self.second_function?
  end

  def self.first_function
  end

  def self.second_function
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wanted the first function available in other places of your project, you would do the following:

```
module MyMod
  def self.call_all_functions
    first_function
    second_function
  end

  def first_function
  end

  def second_function
  end
end
```

If you do not plan to use `first_function` or `second_function` again, it would be better to do this:

```
module MyMod
  def self.call_all_functions
    first_function
    second_function
  end

private

  def first_function
  end

  def second_function
  end
end
```

What private does here is makes those functions only accessible by this one file.

Comment: It seems I was a little backwards. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.